# Community Promotion ad on Raspberry Pi SE

Tags: discussion

Greetings which I hope make it past the remove greetings bot ;)

I added the IoT.SE community promotion ad used in years past at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ to the new [(2019) selection page there](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2134/community-promotion-ads-2019); they must be renewed annually.

That one is pretty good, but if anyone thinks they have a better one, post it here and I will replace it (rather than having competing ads for the same site).  *Be sure you understand the requirements for the image first*, they are in the question on the RPi Meta page linked above.

Also, if you are a voting member at RPi.SE, please upvote the ad, since they must reach a threshold in order to appear.  The specific "answer" [is here](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2137/5538).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, and for the ad!  I've also posted one on [Ask Ubuntu here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/18395/527350).